# How to make points in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need help to make points every time the snake eats a piece of food. I am coding in Brackets.
I've watched The Coding Train and I was thinking the problem was that he was using p5.js when I was using Brackets. Could somebody please answer my question. Thank you! The link for the video that I have watched is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AaGK-fj-BAM.

```js
function Snake() {                                           <- Javascript
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
  this.xspeed = 1;
  this.yspeed = 0;
  this.total = 0;
  this.tail = [];

  this.eat = function(pos) {
    var d = dist(this.x, this.y, pos.x, pos.y);
    if (d < 1) {
      this.total++;
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  this.dir = function(x, y) {
    this.xspeed = x;
    this.yspeed = y;
  }

  this.death = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.tail.length; i++) {
      var pos = this.tail[i];
      var d = dist(this.x, this.y, pos.x, pos.y);
      if (d < 1) {
        alert(' BAD LUCK ');
        this.total = 0;
        this.tail = [];
  point.counterReset;
      }
    }
  }

  this.update = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.tail.length - 1; i++) {
      this.tail[i] = this.tail[i + 1];
    }
    if (this.total >= 1) {
      this.tail[this.total - 1] = createVector(this.x, this.y);
    }

    this.x = this.x + this.xspeed * scl;
    this.y = this.y + this.yspeed * scl;

    this.x = constrain(this.x, 0, width - scl);
    this.y = constrain(this.y, 0, height - scl);
  }

  this.show = function() {
    fill(89, 152, 47);
    for (var i = 0; i < this.tail.length; i++) {
      rect(this.tail[i].x, this.tail[i].y, scl, scl);
    }
    rect(this.x, this.y, scl, scl);

  }
}
var s;
var point = 1;
var scl = 20;

var food;

var fool;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600,600);
  s = new Snake();
  frameRate(10);
  pickLocation();

}

function pickLocation() {
  var cols = floor(width / scl);
  var rows = floor(height / scl);
  food = createVector(floor(random(cols)), floor(random(rows)));
  food.mult(scl);
  fool = createVector(floor(random(cols)), floor(random(rows)));
  fool.mult(scl);
}


function draw() {
  background(120,6,6);
 

  if (s.eat(food)) {
    pickLocation();
    point.total++;
 if (Math.random() * 100 < 45) {
 let name = prompt("What is 2 ÷ 4?");
 alert ("Yes it is, " + name);
 }
    else if (Math.random() * 100 < 45) {
    let name = prompt("What is the intergration of X²?");
    alert ("Yes it is, " + name);
    }
    else if (Math.random() * 100 < 50) {
    let name = prompt("What is Mass x Acceleration?");
    alert ("Yes it is, " + name);
    }
 else if (Math.random() * 100 < 50) {
 let name = prompt("How many elements are in the Periodic Table?");
    alert ("Yes it is, " + name);
 }
 else if (Math.random() * 100 < 50 ) {
    let name = prompt("What is 336 ÷ 84?");
    alert ("Yes it is, " + name);
  }
  
 else if (Math.random() * 100 < 50 ) {
    let name = prompt("(VERY RARE)Who was the captain of The First Fleet?");
    alert ("Yes it is, " + name);
  }
  }
 
  if (s.eat(fool)) {
    pickLocation();
 point.total++;
    if (Math.random() * 100 < 45) {
 let name = prompt("What is 2 ÷ 4?");
 alert ("Yes it is, " + name);
 }
    else if (Math.random() * 100 < 45) {
    let name = prompt("What is the intergration of X²?");
    alert ("Yes it is, " + name);
    }
    else if (Math.random() * 100 < 50) {
    let name = prompt("What is Mass x Acceleration?");
    alert ("Yes it is, " + name);
    }
 else if (Math.random() * 100 < 50 ) {
    let name = prompt("What is 336 ÷ 84?");
    alert ("Yes it is, " + name);
 }
 else if (Math.random() * 100 < 50) {
 let name = prompt("How many elements are in the Periodic Table?");
    alert ("Yes it is, " + name);
 }  
 else if (Math.random() * 100 < 50 ) {
    let name = prompt("(VERY RARE)Who was the captain of The First Fleet?");
    alert ("Yes it is, " + name);
 }
  }

  s.death();
  s.update();
  s.show();


  fill(255, 0, 100);
  rect(food.x, food.y, scl, scl);
  
  fill(255, 0, 100);
  rect(fool.x, fool.y, scl, scl);
 
}


document.write("Score: " + point);

point.update();
point.show();

function keyPressed() {
  if (keyCode === UP_ARROW) {
    s.dir(0, -1);
  } else if (keyCode === DOWN_ARROW) {
    s.dir(0, 1);
  } else if (keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW) {
    s.dir(1, 0);
  } else if (keyCode === LEFT_ARROW) {
    s.dir(-1, 0)
  }
}
```

```css
html, body {                                       <- css
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #40E0D0;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>                                    <-html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/p5.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Snake Game</title>
</head>


 
<body>

 
 
  <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  <script src="snake.js"></script>
  <script src="skin.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am counting points when snake eats apple with that code
`if (cell.x === apple.x && cell.y === apple.y) snake.maxCells++;`

And my snake-game:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('game');

    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var grid = 16;
    var count = 0;
    var snake = {
      x: 160,
      y: 160,
      dx: grid,
      dy: 0,
      cells: [], //tail
      maxCells: 4
    };

    var apple = {
      x: 320,
      y: 320
    };

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

    function loop() {
      requestAnimationFrame(loop);
      if (++count < 1) {
        return;
      }
      count = -15; // speed
      context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
      snake.x += snake.dx;
      snake.y += snake.dy;    

      if (snake.x < 0) {
        snake.x = canvas.width - grid;
      }

      else if (snake.x >= canvas.width) {
       snake.x = 0;
      }

      if (snake.y < 0) {
        snake.y = canvas.height - grid;
      }
      else if (snake.y >= canvas.height) {
       snake.y = 0;
      }
      snake.cells.unshift({x: snake.x, y: snake.y});
      
      if (snake.cells.length > snake.maxCells) {
        snake.cells.pop();
      }
      context.fillStyle = 'red';
      context.fillRect(apple.x, apple.y, grid-1, grid-1);
      context.fillStyle = 'green';
      snake.cells.forEach(function(cell, index) {
        context.fillRect(cell.x, cell.y, grid-1, grid-1);  
        if (cell.x === apple.x && cell.y === apple.y) {  // if our snake eat red apple, so you count points
          // and adding one green cell to snake

          snake.maxCells++;

          // Drawing new apple
        
          apple.x = getRandomInt(0, 25) * grid;
          apple.y = getRandomInt(0, 25) * grid;
        }


        for (var i = index + 1; i < snake.cells.length; i++) {
          if (cell.x === snake.cells[i].x && cell.y === snake.cells[i].y) {
            snake.x = 160;
            snake.y = 160;
            snake.cells = [];
            snake.maxCells = 4;
            snake.dx = grid;
            snake.dy = 0;
            apple.x = getRandomInt(0, 25) * grid;
            apple.y = getRandomInt(0, 25) * grid;
         }
        }
      });
    }
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
      if (e.which === 37 && snake.dx === 0) {
      snake.dx = -grid;
       snake.dy = 0;
      }

      else if (e.which === 38 && snake.dy === 0) {
        snake.dy = -grid;
        snake.dx = 0;
      }

      else if (e.which === 39 && snake.dx === 0) {
        snake.dx = grid;
        snake.dy = 0;
      }

      else if (e.which === 40 && snake.dy === 0) {
        snake.dy = grid;
        snake.dx = 0;
      }
    });
    
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

```css
html, body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
    }

    body {
      background: black;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    canvas {
      border: 1px solid white;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <canvas width="400" height="400" id="game"></canvas> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also I found one more working example. You can check code by this link https://codepen.io/alona-yavorska/pen/OJMVKxV?editors=0010